# Object creation with varying buffer size

Tags: c++

I have a class which allocates array of fixed buffer as below.

```
class CMyBuffer
{
public:
    CMyBuffer() { /* constructor ... */ }
    ~CMyBuffer() { /* destructor ... */ }

    int copy(char *source, int len);

    char        m_szBuf[MYBUF_SIZE * sizeof(char)];
    int         m_nLen;
};
```

When an object of this class is created, there would be memory allocation for the object including the fixed buffer of size MYBUF_SIZE. So as to say there would be one call to malloc() [In good old 'C' thinking].

I was wondering if it is possible to vary the buffer size based on constructor parameter. Of course, it is possible if we make m_szBuf a pointer and allocate memory in the constructor based on the constructor parameter (which specified size). But I think this would end up calling memory allocation twice (once for the object overall and once for the pointer to the buffer within the object). Is there a way to vary the buffer size in the object but with only one call to memory allocation? The concern for exploring this approach is to reduce heap memory fragmentation.

Comment: Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and initialize it using a constructor initializer list to the wanted size? Don't bother with such micro-optimizations unless you have pinpointed it as a serious bottleneck.

Comment: If you use regular arrays - no, it's not possible to change their sizes at run-time. As suggested above, use container classes.

Comment: Can't you use `realloc` for that?

Comment: Since C++11 using `new` or `alloc` directly without RAII pattern is considered as a bad practice. Just use `std::vector` and adjust its capacity by `reserve`. Expression "good old C" is just excuse to write bad C++.

Comment: @Soutuyo No, you can’t, and doing what OP wants is actually pretty hard in strictly conforming C++.

Comment: Question does this `CMyBuffer` have some functionality which `std::vector` or `std::array` doesn't have?

Answer (score 3):

> So as to say there would be one call to malloc() [In good old 'C'
>   thinking].

You are writing c++, not c, right?

In c++ arrays with a size that is only known at runtime are `std::vector`s. For someone used to get their hands dirty it might be a bit lame, but as a matter of fact you really need very good reasons not to use `std::vector`. It is rare that `std::vector` cannot do what you need for a dynamic array.

> I was wondering if it is possible to vary the buffer size based on
>   constructor parameter.

Yes, of course:

```
class CMyBuffer
{
public:
    CMyBuffer(size_t size) : m_szBuf(size) { /* constructor ... */ }
    ~CMyBuffer() { /* destructor ... */ }

    int copy(char *source, int len);   
    std::vector<char> m_szBuf;
};
```

You also do not need to keep track of the size of the vector yourself (that is c-thinking ;).

Maybe you think, well `std::vector` is fine, but it does not help me because I still need a `char*` in some places of my code. However, `std::vector` can give you access to the underlying array via `std::vector::data()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few expected sizes of buffer, and they're known at compile time, you can use templating to generate classes for each size:

```
template <size_t N>
class CMyBuffer
{
    public:
        char m_szBuf[N * sizeof(char)];
        int  m_nLen = N;
};

// usage
CMyBuffer<MYBUF_SIZE> buff;
CMyBuffer<256> buffBig;
```

Comment: `sizeof` is defined in terms of the size of a `char` and `sizeof(char)` is always `1`

Comment: Indeed, I was re-using the questioner's provided code for their readability. Should I edit or is that consistency normally preferred?

Comment: your choice. maybe I should have made the comment on the question rather than here, I just thought it is worth mentioning